# Captcha in JSF 2.0

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2, captcha

In my project I have to integrate Captcha to my Signup Form, I have seen JCaptcha and google recaptcha can anybody suggest me the best and easy way to integrate captcha. Actually I don't want third party captcha like recaptcha so how can i generate my own one. I am using JSF 2.0 and Richfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got Solution : http://javahunter.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/integrating-captcha-in-jsf-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

You can also live longer and work less by using [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) component:

[Captcha](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/captchaHome.jsf)

PrimeFaces works fine with RichFaces.

Comment: my primefaces components are not rendered, richfaces components are rendered fine with JSF 2.0, is it's problem with JSF 2.0, I have to make some special entry in faces-config or web.xml ???